# Rewrite customly generated urls in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I'm using  Wordpress, where I have used my custom designed template, so I'm using custom generated URL's in most cases.

I want my URL to look like: `website_url/details/191/`

I want to rewrite this to more SEO friendly.  I don't know how to write rewrite rules in htaccess and could use your help.

```
add_filter( 'rewrite_rules_array','my_insert_rewrite_rules' );
add_filter( 'query_vars','my_insert_query_vars' );
add_action( 'wp_loaded','my_flush_rules' );

// flush_rules() if our rules are not yet included
function my_flush_rules(){
    $rules = get_option( 'rewrite_rules' );

    if ( ! isset( $rules['(details)/(\d*)$'] ) ) {
        global $wp_rewrite;
        $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
     }
}

// Adding a new rule
function my_insert_rewrite_rules( $rules )
{
    $newrules = array();
    $newrules['(details)/(\d*)$'] = 'index.php?    pagename=$matches[1]&id=$matches[2]';
    return $newrules + $rules;
 }

// Adding the id var so that WP recognizes it
function my_insert_query_vars( $vars )
{
    array_push($vars, 'id');
    return $vars;
}
```

This is what I have added in my function.php but no change.

Comment: Did you check here : https://codex.wordpress.org/User:Amereservant/Editing_and_Customizing_htaccess_Indirectly

Comment: you need to provide your current code.

Comment: http://www.webconfs.com/htaccess-redirect-generator.php

I think you are looking for this.

Comment: $newrules['(details)/(\d*)$'] =  'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&id=$matches[2]'; i have tried this but not working @HelpingHands

Comment: @HelpingHands please check my updated question

Comment: you have spaces inside of your $newrules variable `index.php?    pagename=[...]`